# Global .replace Angular6

Tags: angular, replace, angular6

Im trying to achieve something like this in angular6:

https://jsfiddle.net/o8xufvyj/2/

A way to replace all occurrences of a character in a string.

```
{{string.replace(/-/g, ' ')}}
```

Doesn't work in Angular6. How would I make something like this work in angular6 without using .replace multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work, is because Angular is trying to resolve whatever you put between the "{{ }}" from its current scope (the controller, for example). However, your scope doesn't have anything like "string.replace", so it can't resolve that value.

A solution is simply to put a function in your controller, that modifies the given string, and return it, and then use that function in your HTML.

```
public replace(content: string) {
    return content.replace(/-/g, " ");
}
```

And then in your HTML:

```
{{replace("content-to-be-modified")}}
```

Comment: Thanks, knew I had to use a function but quite new so didn't exactly know how to set this up.

Comment: this correct but this not reusable and if you want to use this method in another component you need to write it again :\

Comment: True, and while it's possible to write this as a static method, you still need to implement some version in the scope of wherever you want to use it in a {{ }} notation.

Comment: call function like this in the template is very bad in term of performance because it will run in every ui change even if it's not related to the funcion value you can you check this example and see the console result when press the button https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-replace-pipe-zedbec

Answer (score 3):

Pipe is reusable and what angular suggest to transform the data so,you can create a pipe to replace the string value base on regex value like this

*replace pipe*

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'replace'
})
export class ReplacePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string, regexValue: string, replaceValue: string): any {
    let regex = new RegExp(regexValue, 'g');
    return value.replace(regex, replaceValue);
  }

}
```

*template*

```
<p> {{stringText | replace:' ':'--'}}</p>
<p> {{stringText | replace:'[a-z]':'--'}}</p>
<p> {{stringText | replace:'[A-Z]':'--'}}</p>
<p> {{stringText | replace:'[a-zA-z]?':'**'}}</p>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-replace-pipe)

Answer (score 1):

Assign the result to public variable.

**Component**

getFormatText(text){
   return text.replace(/-/g, ' ');
}

**Template**

{{getFormatText(text)}}

Comment: The problem im facing with this, that's its inside a *ngFor loop in the HTML. The string in this case i'm replacing is a api call from the for loop. Is there a way I can call a function in {{ }} bracets in the HTML to call for a function that replaces the string?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the template. You should do the replacement in your component, and bind the replaced string in the template.

BTW is a bad idea to try to do such thing in a template, as the replacement will be done every time the view is refreshed.

Comment: The problem im facing with this, that's its inside a *ngFor loop in the HTML. The string in this case i'm replacing is a api call from the for loop. Is there a way I can call a function in {{ }} bracets in the HTML to call for a function that replaces the string?

Comment: Yes, you can use the Suresh's method :D